# Javascript return value position

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and I found this code sample

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

I would like to know if this is the same as the code below where I moved the ***return value*** below the **if condition**?

```
function validateForm() {
 var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
 if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");        
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not the same

Comment: No. The first only returns `false` when the value of `fname` is empty. The second one _always_ returns false.

Comment: @Pimmol Thanks for emphasizing that word _always_. Short and clear answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

No.

Unsurprisingly, moving the `return false` outside the conditional block means you have changed it to **always** return false.

You haven't provided the context of how the function is called, but the most likely effect of this is to change the behaviour from:

> If the field isn't filled out, show an alert and stop the form from submitting. Otherwise, submit the form.

to

> If the field isn't filled out, show an alert and stop the form from submitting. Otherwise, still stop the form from submitting. Just never submit the form under any circumstances.

Comment: I see, it's a bit funny when you said _just never submit the form_. Indeed this is the result of the second version. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. If a `return` statement is missing from a function, you should treat it as if the last line is:

```
return undefined;
```

So, version one:

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Version two:

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");        
  }
  return false;
}
```